# Concatenar y Convertir

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola a todos tengo un ejercicio en el que me piden desarrollar una función llamada concat que tome como parámetros una tupla con valores de tipo str y devuelva un valor de tipo str que será el resultado de concatenar todos los elementos de la tupla pasada como parámetro, en el orden en que aparecen el la misma pero el problema es que no se como se concatena ni como se convierte a string

Por ejemplo:

```
Entra: ("¡Hola", ", ", "mundo!")

Devuelve: "¡Hola, mundo!"
```

Comment: [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) como en `"".join(entrada)`. O quizás quien puso el ejercicio pretende que lo hagas con bucles, en cuyo caso te ayudará saber que el operador para concatenar cadenas es `+`

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la  ayuda. He probado como me has indicado pero en la ejecución me sale error. Y he usado el bucle for pero no se como se usa. Lo he hecho  tal que así:

Comment: def concat(t):                                                                                    for elementos in t:                                                                     texto = (t[0]+t[2])                                                                           return texto                                                                          Y la otra forma primera que me has dicho la he hecho así: Está una línea de código debajo de otra                                                                                     def concat(t):       texto= str.join(t) return texto

Comment: La otra forma fue así:                                                                def concat(t):                                                                                 
 texto = str.join(t).                                                                      return texto.                                                                            TANTO ESTE CÓDIGO COMO EN EL ANTERIOR LE PUSE LOS ESPACIADOS, LOS DOS PUNTOS, ETC NECESARIOOS

Comment: En lugar de `str` tienes que poner una cadena, que contendrá el carácter usado para concatenar los elementos de `t`. Por ejemplo, `"-".join(t)` concatenará los elementos de `t` poniendo un guión entre ellos. Y puedes usar la cadena vacía para que no añada nada entre elementos. Y para el bucle necesitarías tener una cadena inicialmente vacía a la que vayas añadiendo los demás elementos, como en `texto = texto +  elemento`

Comment: El código que has puesto en los comentarios mejor lo pones en la pregunta. Usa el enlace "editar" para modificar tu pregunta. De ese modo se podrá ver correctamente la indentación, espacios, etc.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias nuevamente. Y crear una entrada vacía como sería??

Comment: Una cadena vacía es así `""`. Por tanto antes del bucle debes hacer `texto =""`

Comment: @Gonzalo no abuses de las etiquetas ya que su objetivo principal es señalar las tecnologías involucradas en tu problema. Te recomiendo leer [ask], [answer] y pasar el [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el método **join** de la clase **str** para concatenar los elementos de una secuencia (lista o tupla) en base a un separador:

```
def concat(tupla):
    return ''.join(tupla)

tupla = ('Hola', 'Mundo')
resultado = concat(tupla)
print(resultado) # "HolaMundo"
```

Puedes mejorar esta función con un parámetro que especifique el separador:

```
def concat(tupla, separador=''):
    return separador.join(tupla)

tupla = ('Hola', 'Mundo')
resultado = concat(tupla, separador=" ")
print(resultado) # "Hola Mundo"
```

Si no conoces el método **join**, o el ejercicio propuesto cuenta con que no lo vas a utilizar, puedes redefinir el primer ejemplo del siguiente modo:

```
def concat(tupla):
    temp = ''
    for i in tupla:
        temp += i

    return temp

tupla = ('Hola', 'Mundo')
resultado = concat(tupla)
print(resultado) # "HolaMundo"
```

Aquí se ha utilizado un **bucle for** que itera sobre cada uno de los elementos de la tupla, y va concatenando el valor del elemento a la variable *temp*, que se inicializó como una cadena vacía (**""**).

Finalmente puedes mejorar esta función para que acepte un parámetro que especifique el separador entre las cadenas a concatenar:

```
def concat(tupla, separador=''):
    temp = ''
    for i in tupla:
        temp += i + separador

    return temp

tupla = ('Hola', 'Mundo')
resultado = concat(tupla, separador=" ")
print(resultado) # "Hola Mundo"
```

Un saludo.